# Powershell script to close specific user share drive session

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

Is it possible to clear user shared drive session using powershell script?? We have NAS drive and we clear user sessions by connecting to NAS drive via computer management and then going to shared folders and then sessions and right click on username and close session. I want this to be done via powershell script where i provide userid or username and run the script to close that user NAS drive shared connections

I didn't get any script to close NAS drive shared sessions.